# Text from knockout.js viewmodel not showing in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm woking with MVC 4 playing around with Knockout for the front end architecture. I currently have the following script on my front end...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.merchantName = ko.observable("Store");
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>



<p>Merchant name: <strong data-bind="text: merchantName"></strong></p>
```

The problem is that the data for the merchantName attribute isn't showing in the HTML. I run the same code on in the Knockout tutorial page http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro 
and everything works fine. What do you think could be the issue. Also, I'm relatively new at front end development. What is the best way to debug knockout problems other than chrome debugger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use knockout.js only after your DOM is already loaded. In your example just put

```
<p>Merchant name: <strong data-bind="text: merchantName"></strong></p>
```

to the top of your file.

Also notice, that putting javascript right before `</body>` is closed is good practice in most cases

Comment: That's a pretty simple fix. Why does it see this after the DOM has loaded if it's before the javascript, but not when it's after?

Comment: I didn't read knockout.js source code at the moment, so I have no answer to this question. Answering your question about debugging knockout: in most cases debugging knockout application reduces to debbuging javascript of ViewModel. I'm using chrome devtools, but you can use firebug or something else as well. I have several chrome snippets for unwrapping observables and so on, when I don't want to pass my code through breakpoints but want something like `console.unwrap(data)`. In other cases - nothing new, working with knockout like with vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the below 2 for `ko.applyBindings`:

1. Add at the top of DOM with `document.onload` check
2. At the bottom after DOM is loaded with out any check

From Documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

```
You can either put the script block at the bottom of your HTML document, or you can put it at the top and wrap the contents in a DOM-ready handler such as jQuery’s $ function.
```